# Trouble with math fonts in XeLaTeX

Tags: latex, xelatex

I want to use the "Gentium Plus" font for writing mathematical work (in math mode).
Added `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\usepackage{unicode-math}`.

When compiling XeLaTeX it gives an error:

```
   ! Package unicode-math Error: No main maths font has been set up yet.
   (unicode-math) If you simply want ‘the default’, use:
   (unicode-math)\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
```

and writes math using "Latin Modern Math".

How can I force the use of "Gentium Plus" for math and completely prohibit the transition to the default font (it would be better to have ▯ instead of symbols)?

Template:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, thmtools, unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Gentium Plus}

\begin{document}

\title{Mathematical text}

\section{Section name}

Lorem ipsum

\[
\alpha + \beta = \gamma + \delta.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I complete the question

Comment: I don't see any math font available for Gentium Plus. If you'd like to use the normal text letters and numbers from Gentium Plus in math mode, you could use `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}`

Comment: Or use `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Gentium Plus}` instead of unicode math

Comment: (if you'll disable all fall back to the default font, you won't have much fun writing math as you'll miss most of the symbols...)

Comment: If you aren't death set on Gentium Plus, maybe consider using a font which has math support? For example https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcharter-math might be similar enough.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The solution with mathspec (`\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`) conflicts with some other package (amsmath perhaps?): `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec.`

The **mathastext** solution covers ~90% of the troubles. Only the numbers in mathmode are left ugly (although they can be wrapped with \text{} from amsmath). I tried both `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}` and `\usepackage[basic,italic]{mathastext}`, but the numbers remain "LMRoman".

Comment: I don't get any package conflict with mathspec: https://pastebin.com/h7NHFDtr

Comment: I get Gentium numbers with https://pastebin.com/X8t4s5K0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I force the use of "Gentium Plus" for math and completely prohibit the transition to the default font (it would be better to have ▯ instead of symbols)?

There does not seem to be a Gentium Plus math font available. You won't get happy with writing math if you don't have any symbols etc.

---

Some alternatives:

## `mathastext`

You could use the `mathastext` package to use letters and numbers from the normal text font in math mode:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus} 

\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}

\title{Mathematical text}

\section{Section name}

Lorem ipsum2

abcxyz \itshape abxzyx2

\[
abcxyz2 \alpha + \beta = \gamma + \delta.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

## `mathspec`

You could use the `mathspec` package to load Gentium Plus for letters and digits:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus} 
\usepackage{mathspec} 
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Gentium Plus}
\begin{document}

\title{Mathematical text}

\section{Section name}

Lorem ipsum2

abcxyz \itshape abxzyx2

\[
abcxyz2 \alpha + \beta = \gamma + \delta.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Combine with an actual math font

Instead of the Frankenstein approaches above, you could also pair your font with a real math font, e.g. XCharter might work well with it and you'll get matching symbols etc.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus} 

\usepackage[no-text,Scale=0.93]{xcharter-otf}

\title{Mathematical text}

\begin{document}

\section{Section name}

Lorem ipsum2

abcxyz \itshape abxzyx2

\[
abcxyz2 \sum \int \alpha + \beta = \gamma + \delta.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]